# Database query with WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: database

Can't figure out why the following query executes directly through phpMyAdmin perfectly well:

```
SELECT id FROM `stats` WHERE type="load" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

but firing this:

```
db_query('SELECT id FROM {stats} WHERE type = '.$param.' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')->fetchField();
```

from a module outputs:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'load' in 'where clause': SELECT id FROM {server_stats} WHERE type = load5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; Array ( ) in server_tab_stats_submit() (line 750 of /home/dev/public_html/sites/all/modules/custom/server/server.inc).
```

Column's name there is "type", I don't know why Drupal query thinks "load" is a column, it is just a value derived from $param variable.

Comment: Anil has already answered the right way but .. you need quotes also: type = "'.$param.'" ORDER BY

Comment: Tried this way, unfortunately didn't work. But I am happy with Anil's solution. Thanks!

Comment: [`db_select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) gives you less freedom to err ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$nid = db_query('SELECT id FROM {stats} WHERE type = :type ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1', array(':type' => $param))->fetchField();
```

Refer [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) for more information...